# intent-filter for "choose an action"

Tags: android

When web-page contains file picker, user clicks on button, "choose an action" popup appears (as you can see on picture; also it is Google Chrome).

[image]

What intent-filter should I add to activity in AndroidManifest file in order to my app appeared in "choose an action" list?

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for. Up to now I think @pr3sto 's answer below is the nearest answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. Not perfect, but still...
It is described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider.html). 
You need to add next code to your activity description in AndroidManifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

So you need to choose "Files" option and your application will be available from menu:

[image]
[image]

**I'm still looking for solution to make app available from first 'chooser' menu. If anyone willing to help.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `android.intent.action.PICK` filter inside your activity.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <data android:scheme="folder"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

From the android doc it says about `ACTION_PICK`:

> Activity Action: Pick an item from the data, returning what was
>   selected.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but it is not working. Also I've tried other actions (GET_CONTENT, CHOOSER, INSERT...) and they are also not work. Maybe there is need to be some specific combination of action, category and data...